# Checkbox - in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am working on Edit screen where I am pulling out value from db to check if the checkbox is checked or not.

If it is *unchecked*, it should deselect the checkbox and other controls of this checkbox. In my case the js works perfectly fine. That is if my previous screen has checkbox unchecked, edit screen disables all the values for this checkbox. But it still shows the checkbox is checked in UI(though it is actually checked). Something is wrong with my html code.

Can someone please let me know where /how should i modify  to display if my checkbox is unchecked?

```
<%chkStatus=list.getCheckbox();
         if (chkStatus == null) { chkStatus = ""; }
 %>

   <input id="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="chkbox" checked="<%=chkStatus%>"  
                                onchange="javascript:enableDisableTextBox();">
```

Comment: `<inputid="chkbox"` -> `<input id="chkbox"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checked is a boolean attribute, so you should have:

```
<input id="chkbox" type="checkbox" checked />
```

for the checked state and

```
<input id="chkbox" type="checkbox" />
```

for the unchecked state. (`selected` in `<select><option/> </select>` is an example of another boolean attribute).

Answer (score 0):

Your html looks fine except the input tag,

```
<%chkStatus=list.getCheckbox();
         if (chkStatus == null) { chkStatus = ""; }
 %>

   <input id="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="chkbox" checked="<%=chkStatus%>"  
                                onchange="javascript:enableDisableTextBox();">
```

This might help.

Comment: Rahul,Sorry, I had this <input id="chkbox" correct in my code, while typing I did a mistake here.